# Use NDSolve to solve PDE's with different domains

Tags: differential-equations

Good morning,

I want to find a numerical solution to the following equation using NDSOLVE:

$$
(1)\hspace{1cm}EJ\frac{\partial^4 v}{\partial x^4} +kv+\rho A \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} = q \hspace{1cm} \forall x \in [0;L_o]  
$$

$$
(2)\hspace{1,7cm}EJ\frac{\partial^4 w}{\partial x^4} +\rho A \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2} = q \hspace{1cm} \forall x \in [L_o;L] 
$$

$$
BC_{(1)}:\hspace{1cm} \left|\frac{\partial^3 w}{\partial x^3}\right|_{x=0} =0\hspace{1cm}\left|\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}\right|_{x=0} =0\hspace{1cm}  \forall t  
$$

$$
BC_{(2)}:\hspace{1cm} \left|\frac{\partial^3 v}{\partial x^3}\right|_{x=L} =0\hspace{1cm}\left|\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}\right|_{x=L} =0\hspace{1cm}  \forall t  
$$

$$
BC_{(1\space and\space2)}:\hspace{1cm} \left|\frac{\partial^i v}{\partial x^i}\right|_{x=L_o} = \left|\frac{\partial^i w}{\partial x^i}\right|_{x=L_o} \hspace{1cm} i=0,...,3 \hspace{0,9cm}\forall t  
$$

$$IC_{(1\space and\space2)}:\hspace{1cm} v(x,t)=w(x,t)=0\hspace{1cm}\forall x, \space t=0$$

$$\hspace{3,1cm} \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}=0\hspace{1cm}\forall x, \space t=0  $$

How can I use 'NDSOLVE' and imposing two-domain integration?
As suggested let's think that Eq. (2) is valid in y domain so:
$$
(2')\hspace{1,7cm}EJ\frac{\partial^4 w}{\partial y^4} +\rho A \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2} = q \hspace{1cm} \forall y \in [L_o;L] 
$$
And (as suggested in a comment) let's assume
$$ y=y(x),\hspace{1,7cm} y=L-\frac{x}{L_o}(L-L_o)$$
if it's the case we have:
$$
\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}  \hspace{0,2cm}\rightarrow \hspace{0,2cm} \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2}\Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big)^2 \hspace{0,2cm}  \rightarrow \space...\space\rightarrow \hspace{0,2cm} \frac{\partial^4 w}{\partial y^4}=\frac{\partial^4 w}{\partial x^4}\Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big)^{-4} \hspace{0,2cm}
$$
At the end EQ(2) is replaced with:
$$
(2'')\hspace{1,7cm}EJ\Big(\frac{L_o}{L_o-L}\Big)^4\frac{\partial^4 w}{\partial x^4} +\rho A \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2} = q \hspace{1cm} \forall x \in [0;L_o] 
$$
I wrote this code but is not working.

```
Clear[b, h, Emod, m, Lo, Lf, q, k, J, y, u, v];
b = 0.20; (*m*)
h = 0.20; (*m*)
Emod =10000000000;(*modulo el N/m^2*)
Lo = 2;(*l ini m*)
L = 4;(*l fin m*)
rho = 10;(*rho kN/m^3*)
m = b*h*rho;(*N/m*)
q = 1000;(*N/m*)
k = 50000;(*N*)
P = 0.00000; 
J = (b*h^3)/12;
tmax = 30;
sol = NDSolve[{
     (*1st*)
+Emod*J*D[u[t, x], {x, 4}] + k*u[t, x] == q - m*(D[u[t, x], {t, 2}]),
     (*2nd*)
+Emod*J*(Lo/(Lo - L))^4*D[v[t, x], {x, 4}] + k*v[t, x] == q - m*(D[v[t, x],{t, 2}]),

(*1st boundary conditions*)
Derivative[0, 2][u][t, 0] == 0,
Derivative[0, 3][u][t, 0] == P*2/Pi*ArcTan[t],
(*1st initial conditions*)
u[0, x] == 0,
Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0,

(*2nd boundary conditions*)
(Lo/(Lo - L))^2*Derivative[0, 2][v][t, 0] == 0,
(Lo/(Lo - L))^3*Derivative[0, 3][v][t, 0] == 0,
(*2nd initial conditions*)
v[0, x] == 0,
Derivative[1, 0][v][0, x] == 0,

(*commonn*)
u[t, Lo] == -v[t, Lo],
Derivative[0, 1][u][t, Lo] == (Lo/(Lo - L))*
Derivative[0, 1][v][t, Lo],
Derivative[0, 2][u][t, Lo] == (Lo/(Lo - L))*
Derivative[0, 2][v][t, Lo],
Derivative[0, 3][u][t, Lo] == (Lo/(Lo - L))*
Derivative[0, 3][v][t, Lo]
}, {u, v}, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, Lo}, PrecisionGoal -> 2]
```

---

ADDITIONAL INTERESTING QUESTION:
As suggested in a comment I used "UnitStep" function, but now I want to add an ODE that prescribes the "lenght of UniStep". What I want to do is easy understandable by the following code (but it doesn't work):

```
Lo = 1; L = 3; J = 1; m = 100; Emod = 1; k = 0.5; q = 0.001; tmax = 20;
sol = NDSolve[{
m*D[u1[t, x], {t, 2}] + Emod*J*D[u1[t, x], {x, 4}] + 
UnitStep[Lo + u2[t] - x] k*u1[t, x] == q,
Derivative[0, 2][u1][t, 0] == 0,
Derivative[0, 3][u1][t, 0] == 0,
Derivative[0, 2][u1][t, L] == 0,
Derivative[0, 3][u1][t, L] == 0,
u1[0, x] == -0.001*x,
Derivative[1, 0][u1][0, x] == 0,
D[u2[t], {t,1}] == -NeumannValue[D[u1[t, x], {t, 1}], x == Lo + u2[t]]/
 NeumannValue[D[u1[t, x], {x, 1}], x == Lo + u2[t]],
u2[0] == 0},
{u1, u2}, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, L}, MaxSteps -> 100000]
Plot3D[Evaluate[u1[t, x] /. sol[[1, 1]]], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, L}]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Your code is different on the $u'''(0)$ term to that which you have written in the LaTeX. Do you have a value for `Lo` is, or is that an unknown you need to solve for? This looks sort of like a linear eigenvalue equation, except for the terms in `q`. I can  help if so provided `q=0`.

Comment: I think there is a way to do this by redefining the second domain to lie on top of the first, i.e. solving for both $v$ and $w$ in $0<x<L_0$, having rescaled the $x$ in the second equation something like $\hat{x} = (L - x)/(L-L_0)$ (haven't checked that is correct).

Comment: Thank you. You are right, both equations (1) and (2) are eigenvalue equations. I was thinking to the same change of variables but I'm little warried about the expression for the derivatives with respect to the equation (2). About the boundary conditions I need in total 8 integration constants. So I've 8 equations as you can see. Of course for x=Lo I need to express the Boundary Conditions as a continuity conditions since I do not know the value of the derivatives evaluated at x=Lo.

Comment: Sorry! Now I understand what you mean... I'm going to correct BC1 and BC2. I need to solve it for q different from 0. For this reason I'm using NDSOLVE

Comment: Thank you! I found my fault and I updated the question.

Comment: I've deleted some comments that aren't relevant any more. What exactly are you trying to do with varying the domain size?

Comment: I've deleted some comments with the same purpose. I'm not trying to change the domain size, because the "x domain size" is still L. May be that approach you suggested before is not valid anymore. I'm thinking to move this second question in a separated new question because It doesn't match the title.

Answer (score 5):

As the equations are almost the same in the two domains, and all your conditions at the interface are just continuity, you can easily just combine into one equation by using `UnitStep` to only include the $k$ term in the $v$ region. Here for $L=3$:

```
Lo = 1;
L = 3;
J = 1;
m = 1;
Emod = 1;
k = 0.5;
q = 0.001;
tmax = 100;
sol = NDSolve[{m*D[u[t, x], {t, 2}] + Emod*J*D[u[t, x], {x, 4}] + 
     UnitStep[Lo - x] k*u[t, x] == q, Derivative[0, 2][u][t, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 3][u][t, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 2][u][t, L] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 3][u][t, L] == 0, u[0, x] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0}, u, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, L}, 
  MaxSteps -> 100000]

Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol[[1, 1]]], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, L}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I think that if we fix my code it mean that we found a way to use NDSOLVE for a problem with two or more domains connected each other and in witch we are integrating different equations, or different physical processes. May be some other users can help us.

Comment: I don't think there is a reason why you couldn't just use UnitStep to change the equations entirely.

Comment: For me it'works but I was thinking about that to improve our knowledge on NDSOLVE

Comment: does this trick also work for analytic solutions?

Comment: @IonSme, you can use various piecewise functions (such as `UnitStep or HeavisideTheta) inside `DSolve`, so you can try it.